# Netlogo: how to access current item while looping through a list?

Tags: list, netlogo

I'm new to netlogo and I'm trying to iterate through a list. After some research I discovered I'd have to use a question mark (?) to access the current item. I tried it, but it gave me the following error: nothing named '?' has been defined. This is (a part of) my current code:

```
let klist (list k1 k2 k3 k4)
foreach klist [
  if opdracht = ? [set kans kans + 1]]
```

How do I access the current item?

Comment: Charles' answer is correct, but note that you can also accomplish what you want with: `let kans length filter [ [k] -> k = opdracht ] klist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work in NetLogo 5.3.1, but if you are using NetLogo 6.0, the `foreach` syntax has changed to employ anonymous reporters.  In 6.0 the code would be:

```
foreach klist [[k] ->
  if opdracht = k [set kans kans + 1]
]
```

Charles